# ClassCastException if placing Button above a view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with placing a Button above a separator line created in a `View`. In the following code I place buttons and text as you can see in the picture:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_card_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_card"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_card"
            android:src="@drawable/image10herz" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator_card"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_card_wrapper"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_card_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator_card"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="test1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator_card_info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_card_info"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator_card_info"
        android:text="@string/button_next_card"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_klo_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator_card_info"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_next_card"
        android:text="@string/button_klo_card"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_king"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator_card_info"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_klo_card"
        android:text="@string/button_king"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_music"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/separator_copyright_play"
        android:textOff="@string/button_music_off"
        android:textOn="@string/button_music_on"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator_copyright_play"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_copyright_play"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_copyright_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/text_copyright" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the layout as picture:

[image]

As you can see, I want to display all buttons above this horizontal line and all button in one row with `android:layout_toLeftOf="..."`. Each time I do `android:layout_above="@+id/horizontal_line_bottom"` and the Activity is launched, I get the following `ClassCastException`:

```
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mho.circleofdeathapp/com.mho.circleofdeathapp.PlayActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.widget.ToggleButton
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.widget.ToggleButton
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at com.mho.circleofdeathapp.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:69)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-28 16:48:12.624: E/AndroidRuntime(4260):     ... 11 more
```

In my `onCreate()` method I only cast the Views by ID ot the right buttons (`ToggleButton` and `Button`). This is all working fine if I don't change the settings in the layout XML, but if I do this, I get the corresponding exception if I start the `Activity`.

EDIT: Added onCreate() method.

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    nextCardButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next_card);
    nextCardButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    kloCardButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_klo_card);
    kloCardButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    kingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_king);
    kingButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    soundButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button_music);
    soundButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_card);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(getImage(R.drawable.bier_head));

    cardTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_card_info);

    initialize();
  }
```

Comment: its problem in your activity

Comment: try using tablerow for all your buttons.

Comment: put your activity i will rectify it

Comment: Clean and Build doesn'T solve this problem and it is not a problem within my Activity, cause if the buttons are placed like in the picture, it is working all fine.

Comment: Could you post the few lines around `com.mho.circleofdeathapp.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:69)` ? Also you don't have a `@+id/horizontal_line_bottom`, I guess you mean `@+id/separator_copyright_play` ?

Comment: @Nerkatel Yes sorry I mean this.

Comment: @TonyStark You're right. It is in my activity, but where is the problem...I placed the buttons now over the bottom horizontal line and commented the activity initialization and now it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution for may problem, but I don't know why this is working. For every button, I removed the tag `android:visibility="visible"` and now it is working.